# LaTeX regex working on RegExr but not in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm trying to match TeX commands like `\def` and `\char` in VSCode `settings.json` with the following regex:

```
(?<!%.*)(\\\\)(def|char)(\\b|[^[a-z]]|[0-9])
```

This correctly matches `\def` and `\char` but also matches any uppercase version of them, like `\Def` or `\chAr`. When I put this into RegExr, making sure the `\`s aren't escaped a second time for the JSON file, it works perfectly. What's going wrong?

Edit: I'm using the Highlight extension.

Comment: Probably, you should look for any ignore case option in that extension and disable it. In an ECMAScript regex, there is no way to swap case sensitivity.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. There's no option to remove ignore case, but adding the regex flag `g` works for some reason.

Comment: Well, that is really weird if it helps with case sensitivity :)